# Presto sql case if- can I choose just a few case and have the original output for other results?

Tags: sql, presto

I've got 4 values in one columns that I want to change. I'm planning on doing this using an case if statement.

However, we sometimes see other values outside of the original ones. I would like for these to come out unprocessed.

Unfortunately, the other values do change, while the values that I will change will stay the same

something like this[image]

Comment: I see a problem with your dat model.  You should not be storing multiple values in a single column, and certainly not as a string.

Comment: Would you share the current sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column is a string I suggest you use: `split -> Filter`

Ex:

```
filter( split(original,'|') , x -> x in [Wanted elements])
```

Documentation:

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html